# How can I define array length in class? Getting length undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-class

I have to write all actors from array, each one should be on the new line. So far I have this code.

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(movieName, releaseDate, actors) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.actors = actors;
  }
  printDetail() {
    console.log(this.movieName);
    console.log(this.releaseDate);

    function actrs() {

      for (let i = 0; i < Movie.actors.length; i++) {
        console.log("test if this actually works");
      }

    }
    actrs();
  }
}

let movie1 = new Movie("moviename", "releasedate", ["John Jackies", "Jack Johnies"]);
movie1.printDetail();
```

So, I am talking about "for" cycle. How can I define the array length of it? Whatever I do, I always get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')".

Comment: Movie is an object that doesn't have an instance, so `Movie.actors` is undefined. You likely want `this.actors.length`

Comment: Remove the function `actrs`. It is unnecessary and changes the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) (but undefined) property of `Movie`, while `actors` is a member property defined when a new `Movie` instance is constructed.

The `actors` property should be accessed using the `this` keyword, which refers to the `Movie` *instance*.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.actors.length; i++) { /* ... */ }
// or
this.actors.forEach((actor) => { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance variable instead. Also, remove the `actrs` function since it is unneeded and changes the value of `this`.

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(movieName, releaseDate, actors) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.actors = actors;
  }
  printDetail() {
    console.log(this.movieName);
    console.log(this.releaseDate);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.actors.length; i++) {
      console.log("test if this actually works");
    }
  }
}

let movie1 = new Movie("moviename", "releasedate", ["John Jackies", "Jack Johnies"]);
movie1.printDetail();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I am sure I used "this" before, it just did not work, and now it suddenly works. I don't know why but thank you!

Comment: @DaveHan because you had the `actrs` function inside `printDetail`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. You are referring to `Movie`. Which has no static fields or methods. What you want is your instance of it. The correct way to do this, as you know, is using the `this` keyword.

I'm guessing you tried it in your for-loop, but it didn't work. This is because the `this` context is different in a `function`. For it to work, you will have to change `Movie.actors.length` to `this.actors.length`, and then bind the function after its declaration:

```
const boundActrs =  actrs.bind(this);
actrs();
```

This will get it to work. An alternative is to use an arrow function, which doesn't change the `this` context:

```
const actrs = () => {    
  for (let i = 0; i < this.actors.length; i++) {
    console.log("test if this actually works");
  }
}
```

However, this isn't clean code. I would make this a private function, or just have the for-loop in `printDetail` without the extra function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an array and assuming you will always pass an array, you can safely use forEach to print each actor.

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(movieName, releaseDate, actors) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.actors = actors;
  }
  printDetail() {
    console.log(this.movieName);
    console.log(this.releaseDate);
    this.actors.forEach(a => console.log(a));
}
}

let movie1 = new Movie("Jurrasic Park", "1/1/12", ["John Jackies", "Jack Johnies"]);
movie1.printDetail();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const $this = this;
function actrs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < $this.actors.length; i++) {
        console.log("test if this actually works");
    }
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.